# finding proportion/ratio for clamping a font size given a min/ideal/max font size and min/current/max screen width

Tags: responsive-design

I am trying to create a clamping formula (same logic from CSS) to make the typography more responsive in PowerApps. I have a minimum, maximum and an ideal size that is a dynamic calculation. Which gives us:

```
Max(min_,(Min(ideal_),max_)))
```

Now I am struggling to find that ratio. In my case the screen width will never go lower than 360px and the min font size for this example is 16px, the max 40px, when the screen is large/extra large (meaning anything above 900px in our case).

Now how can I represent a formula that calculates a value in between these two that considers the current width of the screen? This has very little to do with PowerApps is more of a math question and general responsive design, I just don't know how to do it :D

I could guess compound proportion as in:

```
16 px f -> 360px w
x px f -> current px w
40 px f -> > 900 px w
```

Is this logic right? What do I do now? This might look obvious to you so please try to guide through or give some video/link/article.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever wondering about this. I think I found the answer.

```
Max(minsize_,(Min((minsize_+(maxsize_-minsize_)*((App.Width - App.MinScreenWidth) / (maxscreenwidth_ - App.MinScreenWidth))),maxsize_)))
```

Taken and adapted from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/